# Android : playing back a song to caller?

Tags: android

I gotta scenario, where i have to play a song to the caller, when someone calls to you then you need to programmatically answer the call and have to play a song. I think it is not possible with android sdk. Can anyone please give me an idea what is the way to do this task ?

Atleast give me what is possible way to finish this task ?

Comment: Nothing i have no idea, using reflection i answered call programmitically